# How do I animate a circle to move horizontally?

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

xvalues = np.arange(4000000, 6000000+1000, 1000).tolist()
yvalues = [5000000]*2001

Acc_11 = xvalues
Acc_12 = yvalues

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.set_xlim((0, 10000000))
axes.set_ylim((0, 10000000))

point, = plt.Circle((4000000, 5000000), 60000, color = "black")


def ani(coords):
    point.set_data([coords[0]],[coords[1]])
    return point

def frames():
    for acc_11_pos, acc_12_pos in zip(Acc_11, Acc_12):
        yield acc_11_pos, acc_12_pos

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, ani, frames=frames, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

Im getting TypeError: 'Circle' object is not iterable. What I need to do? The size of a circle must be changable and related to axes, so matplotlib circle is the only option (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution (assuming you are running in a jupyter notebook cell):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import HTML

xvalues = np.arange(4000000, 6000000+1000, 1000).tolist()
yvalues = [5000000]*2001

Acc_11 = xvalues
Acc_12 = yvalues

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

axes.set_xlim((0, 10000000))
axes.set_ylim((0, 10000000))

point = plt.Circle((4000000, 5000000), 60000, color = "black")

def init():
    point.center = (5, 5)
    axes.add_patch(point)
    return point,

def ani(i):    
    point.center = (Acc_11[i],Acc_12[i])
    return point

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, 
                     ani, 
                     init_func=init, 
                     frames=200, #len(Acc_11), 
                     interval=10)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

You may want to change `frames=200` to `frames=len(Acc_11)` but it will take a while to run.

Comment: Thank you fo helping, but Im looking for solution without Ipython. Is that even possible? Im just beginner with Python..